# sqlalchemy delete index out of range

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have tried many combinations to get my delete to work but I have to be missing something fundamental.  Pointers?  I am trying to delete from api_connectors table where connector_id == 29 (the value of connectorSelected[0]).

```
session = apiconnectors.loadSession()
criteria = "connector_id == '" + str(connectorSelected[0]) + "'"
session.query().filter(criteria).delete()
session.commit()
```

I am getting a warning

```
Textual SQL expression "connector_id == '29'" should be explicitly declared as text("connector_id == '29'")
```

and I am getting an error when the session.query statement runs - but I know from looking in the db the row I am trying to delete does exist.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

You need sqlalchemy’s `text()` function for raw sql queries and then call `first()` method to get result:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

session.query().filter(text("connector_id=='29'")).first().delete()
```